# How Pandavas Fathers were Devas?

Tags: mahabharata

Yudhishthira father was Dharmaraja
Bhima father Vayu
And Arjuna father was Indra

But all of them vayu, yamraj and Indra are Devas (Non humans)
How is this possible?

And karna Father was surya.

How is it possible that someone father is Sun?

Comment: If you are asking, how can an inanimate thing like the Sun father a child, that's just how Hindu mythology works. So your current question will be most likely be closed as "Opinion-based (This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.)" Maybe you can try converting it to something like, Do any Hindus believe that a human being was the biological parent of Karna, Yudhishthira, Arjuna, etc. as opposed to devas like Surya, Dharma and Indra? If so, who were the human fathers of Karna & Yudhishthira?

Comment: Yes the answer can be opinion based.  However, there is a different angle to the issue.  If if treat the issue, as an experiment on Artificial Insemination, conducted by scientists of that age, we have a different angle.

Answer (score 0):

Thats just the way it is - it is the NORM and not the exception in Hinduism. Hardly anyone of importance gets born through the normal human biological process:

(1) Ganesa born from Parvati alone

(2) Sita found by Janaka in a field

(3) Vishnu directly descending into the womb of Devaki for the Krishna avatara

(4) Drona born from a vat containing his father's semen

(5) Iyappan is the offspring of Vishnu as Mohini and Siva

(6) Birth of Kartikeya from the Krittikas with Agni carrying Siva' semen.

(7) Kauravas born from jars.

Comment: Avatar (5) Iyappan is folklore.